# Multicollinearity problems with `polr` function in the MASS package for ordinal response

Tags: r, regression, logistic, ordinal-data, multicollinearity

I've been trying to use the `polr` function for a couple days now. The dataset has lot of features (~70) and some of them are factor variables. When I run a simple `glm` on a response threshold, some dummy variables as found to be making the design matrix multicollinear - 4 of them.

When I run `polr` on the data, it finds the same variables and tries to leave them out. I added print statements to `polr` using `trace` to verify my assumption.

However, when I run `summary(polr)`, I get an error saying the `start` variable isn't long enough. Its actually 4 short. The exact error thrown is:

```
"'start' is not of the correct length"
```

I've experimented with the formula passed to `polr()` to be very sure that start is always found short by the same amount as the number of variables (dummy or otherwise) removed to avoid multicollinearity.

Here's sample code to see this problem (I've made small print adds using `trace()`):

```
r = c(2,2,2,3,3,3,1,1,1,1)
r = as.factor(r)
x = c(0,0,0,4,5,6,0,-1,-1,1)
y = c(5,5,2,1,0,3,10,4,3,8)
z = c(0,0,0,4,5,6,0,-1,-1,1)
a = data.frame(r,x,y,z)

library(MASS)
model <- polr(r~x*y*z, data=a)

[1] "Killing the following coefs."
[1] "z"   "y:z"
Warning messages:
1: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred 
2: In polr(r ~ x * y * z, data = a) :
  design appears to be rank-deficient, so dropping some coefs

summary(model)

Re-fitting to get Hessian
[1] "Length of start mismatch: 7 != 7 + #intercepts"
Error in polr(formula = r ~ x * y * z, data = a, Hess = TRUE, start = c(object$coefficients,  : 
'start' is not of the correct length
```

Hints?

PS - Even when I start throwing variables out of my analysis, I notice that when the number of variables is large, I hit this error quite frequently:

```
Error in svd(X) : infinite or missing values in 'x'
```

Is `MASS` even a stable package?

Comment: Please add a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1217536) for people to work with.

Comment: @gung Its great to be vigilant but you need to respect the fact that I'm new here. You wrote one comment and did not give me time to respond to it. I'm adding code. I just thought it up. If you read my explanation, I think I've explained rather well.

Comment: @gung Edited. Please take a look again.

Comment: Don't take it personally. Questions about how to get R to do stuff, & error messages, are generally off topic here, but potentially on topic on [SO]. To be on topic there, you need a reproducible example, though. W/o one, your Q gets closed here & stops, but w/ one, it can be migrated to SO, where you can get an answer. Some 'I am having a problem w/ R' questions are actually about misunderstanding the statistical issues (any software would behave the same), though. So a reproducible example also helps us diagnose if the Q really does belong here.

Comment: The concern is: this is more statistics that SO usually has. So, I was unsure. And no. I didn't take it personally. Your first 2 comments were less than a minute apart and that was, I believe, a tad bit unfair. :)

Comment: R is a programming language for statistics. R programming often has a statistical component (as opposed to, say, C++). The question is, which aspect needs to be explained, the statistical aspect or the programming aspect; that decides where a Q goes. You're right, those comments are pro forma; they always come back-to-back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example doesn't quite work for me.  I need to add:

```
r = factor(r, levels=1:3, ordered=T)
```

From there, I don't get all the problems you report.  For example, I don't get the messages:

> `[1] "Killing the following coefs."`
>     `[1] "z"   "y:z"`

I do get the warning messages, though.  The first warning message, `1: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred`, is due to perfect separation in your example.  I don't know if you also have separation in your real dataset, but you might.  There are a number of threads on CV that deal with this issue; you can find them by searching under the [hauck-donner-effect](/questions/tagged/hauck-donner-effect) tag.

The second warning message, `2: In polr(r ~ x * y * z, data = a) : design appears to be rank-deficient, so dropping some coefs`, is due to perfect multicollinearity.  I gather you are familiar with multicollinearity already, but you can read some of the threads listed under the [multicollinearity](/questions/tagged/multicollinearity) tag, if you'd like.

Regarding your problems with calling `summary(model)`, I notice that the documentation for [?polr](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/MASS/html/polr.html) states:

> Hess  logical for whether the Hessian (the observed information matrix) should be returned. Use this if you intend to call summary or vcov on the fit.

I don't have the problems you report when I run:

```
model <- polr(r~x*y*z, data=a, Hess=TRUE)
summary(model)
# Call:
# polr(formula = r ~ x * y * z, data = a, Hess = TRUE)
# 
# Coefficients:
#         Value Std. Error    t value
# x     133.246      34947  3.813e-03
# y      -9.662     105406 -9.166e-05
# x:y   -20.739      33468 -6.197e-04
# x:z   -25.087     156572 -1.602e-04
# x:y:z   5.340      30840  1.732e-04
# 
# Intercepts:
#     Value        Std. Error   t value     
# 1|2     -70.2750  531946.6299      -0.0001
# 2|3       8.7140 1249186.4665       0.0000
# 
# Residual Deviance: 2.070293e-09 
# AIC: 14.00
```

I don't get the error message: `Error in svd(X) : infinite or missing values in 'x'`, so I don't know what that is about.

Yes, `MASS` is a stable package.  There are, however, a number of ways to run an ordinal logistic regression in R.  They are discussed [here](http://www.uni-kiel.de/psychologie/rexrepos/posts/regressionOrdinal.html).  If you don't like `MASS`, you can always try some of the others.

Comment: Thanks for that 101. :) Are you familiar with `trace("foo", edit=TRUE)`? I use that inject prints to inform me about the problem better. And yes. I know about multicollinearity. Otherwise, I wouldn't be able to formulate the question. :)  (Also, I think you might have taken a snapshot before I added in `r = as.factor(r)` in the example above.)

Comment: And yes. You are correct. If I use Hess=TRUE, the problem does indeed seem to go away on this example.

Comment: @Navneet, I didn't run `trace()`. Does the problem not go away w/ your real dataset when you set `Hess=TRUE`? If so, I need something to work with to figure out what's going on.

Comment: This problem is solved. I am seeing `Error in svd(X) : infinite or missing values in 'x'` problems in my real dataset now. Any hints on how to solve for that?

Comment: @Navneet, unfortunately not off the top of my head. I don't think I've ever seen that. If you can reproduce it, I can see if I can figure it out.

Comment: @Navneet late reply, but I fixed that by scaling my independent variables